# Why am I getting wrong answer for this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the product of the roots of the equation $2x^2+6x+ y^2 + 2 = 0$ is $−y$ ,then the value of $y$ is.

How I solved:

$xy = -y$ is given

$x = -1$

How I did further:

I put value of $x$ as $-1$ and solved it.
Putting in equation I got $y  = \sqrt{3}$

It also satisfies the equation ,

-1*$\sqrt{3} = -\sqrt{3}$.

But the answer in my book is $2$. I am not getting how they solved it that way

Comment: The polynomial is $2x^2+6x+y^2+2$?  But then the product of the roots is $\frac {y^2+2}2$ so we have $\frac {y^2+2}2=-y$ which is an ordinary quadratic.  I don't understand what you wrote.

Comment: "xy = -y".  Why?  You have no reason to assume $x$ and $y$ are the roots.

Comment: x is given in equation only. Along with coefficients.it is that I can’t assume y as others root but x I can

Comment: It looks like you misread ‘the product of the roots’ as ‘the product of the variables’.  The variables are x and y, but the roots are the solutions (for x, presumably) of the equation.

Comment: @user282657 So if you can't assume $y$ is a root why do you believe the product of the roots is $xy$ ??

Comment: To be fair it is a badly worded question.  It doesn't state the roots *in terms of $y$* or tell you to treat $x$ as a variable and $y$ as a constant.  But that is the only way the question makes sense.  If the polynomial has *two* variables the roots are in the form of an ordered pair and the "product" doesn't make sense and the product equally a variable doesn't either.  The only way to interpret this is a $y$ is a constant and $x$ is a variable. The product of the roots is equal to $-y$.  What is $y$?  By the way... I don't get solution $y$.  I don't get any real solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the roots of quadratic polynomial can be found using:

$$\text{a}x^2+\text{b}x+\text{c}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{-\text{b}\pm\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{ac}}}{2\text{a}}\tag1$$

So, in your case we get:

$$2x^2+6x+\text{y}^2+2=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{6^2-4\cdot2\cdot\left(\text{y}^2+2\right)}}{2\cdot2}=$$
$$\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{5-2\text{y}^2}}{2}\tag2$$

So, the product gives:

$$\frac{-3+\sqrt{5-2\text{y}^2}}{2}\cdot\frac{-3-\sqrt{5-2\text{y}^2}}{2}=\frac{2+\text{y}^2}{2}\tag3$$

Now, we get:

$$\frac{2+\text{y}^2}{2}=-\text{y}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{y}=-1\pm i\tag4$$

Where $i^2=-1$

Answer (score 2):

The product of roots of $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ is $$c/a$$
In your case we have $$ c/a = (y^2+2)/2 =-y $$
$$y^2+2y+2=0$$

Solving for $y$ you get $$ y=-1\pm i$$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was that you assumed $x$ and $y$ are the roots of the equation you wrote.
The given equation is quadratic in terms of $x$ and it has 2 roots, that is, there are two values of $x$ that make that quadratic expression equal to zero. The question refers to those two values, and their product. In this sense, at the beginning of your solution you should consider $x$ as a variable and $y$ as just a number, or a parameter.

In general, the product of the roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ equals $\frac{c}{a}$. You can verify that by multiplying the roots $\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ and $\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ .

With this consideration, you can see that the text of the problem gives an additional piece of information about $y$. Then, you can consider $y$ as an unknown variable that should satisfy that additional piece of information. The calculations are as shown by Derik.

Answer (score 0):

$x, y$ are not that roots of the polynomials.  $x$ is just a variable that expesses the polynomial and $y$ is a fixed constant.

Okay, the person who gave the question should have pointed that out but that is the only interpretation that makes sense.

If $x$ and $y$ are both unfixed variables but then a "root" is an ordered pair $(c_x, c_y)$ that makes the statement true.  But talking of a product of ordered pairs doesn't make sense and even if it didn't the result would be a constant.  It couldn't be the negative of a *variable* $y$.  So to say the product of the roots is $-y$ means that $y$ is *not* a variable but some constant value.

Alternative if $x$ and $y$ are both fixed constants the question doesn't make sense.  You just have and equation involving number like $2(-2)^2 + 6(-2)+(\sqrt 2)^2 + 2= 0$.  It doesn't have any "roots".

So the only way to think of this is that we have a variable $x$ and $y$ is constant number, call it $c$.  and we have the equation $2x^2 + 6x + c^2 +2 = 0$.  That equation will have two roots.  Call them $x_1$ and $x_2$.

We are give $x_1x_2 = -c$ so what is $c$.

Well be the quadratic equation if $2x^2 +6x + c^2 + 2 = 0$ then the two roots are $x_1 = \frac {-6+ \sqrt{6^2 - 4*2*(c^2+2)}}{2*2}$ and $x_1= \frac {-6 - \sqrt{6^2-4*2*(c^2+2)}}{2*2}$.

So we need to solve $\frac {-6+ \sqrt{6^2 - 4*2*(c^2+2)}}{2*2} \frac {-6 - \sqrt{6^2-4*2*(c^2+2)}}{2*2}= -c$.

Can you do that?  Hint: notice that because $(m-n)(m+n) = m^2 - n^2$ we have

$\frac {-6+ \sqrt{6^2 - 4*2*(c^2+2)}}{2*2} \frac {-6 - \sqrt{6^2-4*2*(c^2+2)}}{2*2}=$

$\frac {(-6)^2 - \sqrt{6^2-4*2*(c^2+2)}^2}{2*2*2*2}=$

$\frac {6^2 - (6^2 -4*2*(c^2+2))}{16} = $

$\frac {4*2*(c^2+2)}{16} = \frac {c^2+2}2$

So you must solve $\frac {c^2 + 2}2 = -c$. So

$c^2 + 2 = -2c$ and $c^2 +2c + 2 = 0$ and so $c = \frac {-2 \pm \sqrt{2^2 - 4*2}}2=\frac {-2\pm \sqrt{-4}}2 = -1 \pm \sqrt {-1} = -1 \pm i$.

I do not get any real value.

Someone can double check my work.